# How to curve just one face

Tags: bezier-curves, faces

I have an object of which I would like to curve one face.

What I have:

[image]

What I want to do:

[image]

My final goal is to model a television:

[image]

My blend file:

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34647

How do I curve just one face?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would add a few loop cuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and then use proportional editing to pull the middle cut out (from side view), you can change the falloff type to *spherical* at the bottom of the view to get a more rounded look.

[image]
*loop cuts*

[image]
*spherical falloff*

[image]
*pulling cut out*

Comment: where is spherical falloff?

Comment: @SoluableNonagon You're too quick! :D  See newly added screenshots.

Answer (score 13):

A different approach (than my [other answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26237/5705))  would be to modify the mesh slightly so that you could perform a bevel operation.

Beveling rounds off a corner, so you need a corner where you want the rounded part instead of a flat face.  I accomplished this by connecting the two edges across the face and moving the new edge to a positing where it's two adjoining faces are at right angles.

[image]

You can then select the new edge and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bevel the edge into a curve, using the mouse wheel to control the number of subdivisions.

[image]

Comment: +1. This is quite a bit cleaner than the proportional editing approach, IMO.

Comment: @WChargin The problem is that it creates n-gons.